# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name in Java on select count on function return

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am getting Table not found exception for the following query

```
select count(1) from (pkg_queries.query1function(id));

Type table_type is  Table of record_type
```

query1function is a function from the package which returns table_type.

In java code on prepared statement execution, the select query gives an Invalid Table name Exception. The Same query is successfully executed in Oracle SQL developer.

Is it possible that it is a Java Oracle Driver issue? How to resolve it?

Comment: Your title says you're getting ORA-00903, but then you refer to table not found, which sounds like `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`; they are different things. Assuming you're connected as the same user you tested with in SQL Developer so this isn't just a privilege issue, which database and driver version are you using; and does it make a difference if you remove the parentheses; or turn them into a table collection expression, i.e. `from table (pkg_queries.query1function(id))` ?